# Iterating over multidimensional array with variable length d3

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array of integer values that I want to use to create a bar graph in d3.js The catch is that there can be variable number of values in a particular row. For every row, I want to create a color coded rectangle based on the value of the element. Also the height of each rectangle depends on how many values are present in a row and the average of values in each row

Please see how the graph should look like here:
Variable length bar graph: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYZAe.png

In the above figure each column represents values in a row in multidimensional array. Now the problem I face is that I cannot iterate over multidimensional array when performing the following:

```
bar = svg.selectAll(".bar")
.data(allrankings)
.enter().append("rect")
```

Note : allrankings is the multidimensional array.

What I am presently doing is creating another big array with all rankings in one dimension and iterating over it while keeping track of which row does the element belongs to. Is there a better approach to this problem?

Comment: I think you need a stacked bar chart. Refer here https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208

Comment: The problem is that there are varying elements in each column. So stacked bar chart might not solve the problem I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You can access multidimensional data by using svg groups and multiple .data calls. You can read more from Mike Bostock's tutorial on nested selections: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/#data

In your case, if allrankings was a multidimensional array like [[0,1,2,3],[2,3]], the code can be something like:

```
// process the data so the average and number of elements are visible to each bar
var data = allrankings.map(function(rankings){
    var avg;
    avg = rankings.reduce(function(a,b){ return a+b; })/rankings.length;
    return rankings.map(function(d){
        return {val: d, avg: avg, numBars: rankings.length};
    });
});

var barGroups = svg.selectAll(".bar-groups")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i){
     return "translate("+ i*20 + ",0)"; // may want to use scales
   })
  .classed("bar-groups",true);

var bars = barGroups
  .selectAll(".bars")
  .data(function(d){ 
    return d; // returns a one dimensional array of objects
   })
  .enter()
  .append("rect");
```

then you can assign values via the .avg, .val, and .numBars properties (e.g. `bars.attr("height", function(d){ return d.avg/d.numBars; });`

Gilsha posted a nice example of something similar used in stacked bar charts at https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208